# Avoiding typing redundancy when generating strings with elements separated by a token

Tags: python, string, design-patterns, refactoring

Lets say I have a list of words and I want to print them all separated by a comma and a space. So, for example, lets say the list `l` contains the items `['banana', 'apple', 'pear']` and I would like to produce the string `"banana, apple, pear"`

Now, the approach I would use to solve the problem is as follows:

```
s = ""
s += l[0]
for i in range(1, len(l)):
    s += ", %s" % l[i]
```

Or something very similar to the above. The problem is the the extra assignment on line 2 seems a little bit messy and redundant, seeing as it's almost identical to line 4 with the exception of adding a comma and a space. While this isn't too much of a problem for very small expressions, it can get rather annoying and unpleasant looking for large expressions. For example if instead of `l[0]`, we might have `foo(bar(l[0]) + foobar(l[0]) + ...` which just doesn't feel right to have to repeat the very similar statement just a couple lines below. Is there a better way of achieving the result desired without the extra redundancy? This could include answers specific to the python standard libraries or a general pattern that could be used across multiple languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, one would simply write:

```
s = ', '.join(l)
```

For example:

```
>>> l = ['banana', 'apple', 'pear']
>>> ', '.join(l)
'banana, apple, pear'
```

> This could include [...] a general pattern that could be used across multiple languages.

In other languages, the pattern I typically use is as follows (expressed here in pseudo-Java):

```
for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
  if (i != 0) {
    s += ", ";
  }
  s += l[i];
}
```

This avoids the duplicated assignment.

Comment: Wow, ok, that was extremely obvious for the python call. Thanks, I'll set this as the correct answer as soon as the ten minute period elapses

Answer (score 0):

you can use join: `s = ', '.join(l)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
", ".join(l)
```